# Move table from Outlook to Excel without format change

Tags: excel, outlook

I am stuggle on this situation and have no idea how to figure it out, could someone help me on this??
I was thinking about VBA in Excel, but i have no idea how to let Column H to concate according to how many rows been merged in each project.

And i saw that someone shows that if i copy the table from Outlook and paste it in Google Sheet first and then copy it from Google Sheet and paste it to Excel, it will be exactly what i need it to be. But so sad that my company restricted the access to Google, so i have no idea how to do this.

And i searched on the internet for whole morning and i cannot find anyone ask something similar with me...

This would be very good if anyone have idea on this.

This is the report i get from the system (sent to Outlook)

[image: 1]

This is how it looks when i copy the table from Outlook and pasted it to Excel

[image: 3]

This is what i want to it to be

[image: 2]

Please see above description

Answer (score 1):

Modify Alignment for the columns E:H range.

Set the Alignment tab **Vertical** property to `Center`

[image]